# Calculating Surface Roughness from Land Cover Data/Land Elevation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, topography, vegetation-index

I'm trying to create a surface roughness file over the continental United States in NetCDF format. I've surface elevation file of 200 meters resolution and land cover data of 30meters resolution. I'm trying to create the roughness file in ArcMap.

Can anyone suggest any approach which can be used to calculate the roughness?

Comment: Here's a paper that I wrote recently that discusses calculating roughness from DEMs. It will at least give you some ideas about the types of metrics used for it, the difference between surface complexity and elevation variability, and the issue of scale: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326996619_Hyper-scale_analysis_of_surface_roughness

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?